# How to define SetNull option over tables in SQL properly?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first

I have two tables in my project. Categories and Products. Surely there's a one-to-many relationship.

```
public class Category : BaseClass
    {
        [MaxLength(50)]
        [Required]
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public IFormFile? Picture { get; set; }
        public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
    }
public class Product : BaseClass
    {
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public string? Description { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(50)]
        [Required]
        public string Price { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string? OldPrice { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public IFormFile? Picture { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string? DescriptionFileName { get; set; }
        public int? CategoryId { get; set; }
        public Category Category { get; set; }

    }
public abstract class BaseClass
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string PictureName { get; set; }
    }
```

Here's the AppDb class

```
public class AppDb : DbContext
    {
        public AppDb(DbContextOptions<AppDb> options) : base(options)
        {

        }
        public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Category>()
                .HasMany(c=> c.Products)
                .WithOne(p => p.Category)
                .HasForeignKey(p => p.CategoryId)
                .IsRequired(false)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull);
        }

    }
```

I can't set the child row to null on deleting the parent one. It gets this error ***Cannot create the foreign key "FK_Products_Categories_CategoryId" with the SET NULL referential action, because one or more referencing columns are not nullable.***

Comment: Hi, what EF Core version are you using? Also do you have NRT (Nullable Reference Types) enabled for the project? If yes, then you probably need to change `public Category Category { get; set; }` to `public Category? Category { get; set; }`

Comment: The error message indicates that you are adding data and one of the properties marked REQUIRED is null.  You can either add the missing data or remove required from the property.

Comment: @IvanStoev Hi. I'm using EF core version 7.0.3. I don't have any idea what NRT is and how to find out whether it's enabled or not, but I'm using VS 2022. I tried your code, but still failed.

Comment: @jdweng Id in BaseClass is a primary key. CategoryId in Product class is a nullable integer. So which property the error is referring to? I can't set the primary key to be nullable, right?

Comment: The error message is referring to `CategoryId` which is nullable, both as type `int?` and fluent configuration. However NRT could cause EF Core to make it required if it decides that the navigation property `Category Category` is required. It is explained here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/entity-properties?tabs=data-annotations%2Cwithout-nrt#required-and-optional-properties. So try my initial suggestion, but make sure you regenerate the migration after modifying the class.